# Error in redifining the same directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem in defining the same directive in different js file. I have created a directive for multiselectDropDown in say x.js, Again i want the similar drop down in different js file say y.js . So i have defined the same one in both the files. But I am getting an error saying "Error: $compile:multidir Multiple Directive Resource Contention ".Can't I define same directive in two different files?

Comment: how can you use same name of directive `multiselectDropDown`??

Comment: so you want to create duplicate code on purpose? shame on you.

Comment: So i can change the name of the directive alone? @Saurabh Agarwal

Comment: yeah try with different name

Comment: @HorstJahns I want the same directive in other file.Do you have a better idea then suggest

Comment: you don't have to repeat the js code... but just repeat the directive in your html template!!

Comment: you register the directive to a module and afterwards you can access it from anywhere in that module or add a dependency to your module.

Comment: In other words the directive does not need to be in the same file as code that uses it. It can be totally different file as long as it's the same module or module that is referenced from this other file.

Comment: Thanks everyone.It worked :)